# EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    NUMBER_OF_DAYS = 10
    NUMBER_OF_HOURS = 24
    data = []
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_DAYS):
        data.append([])
        for j in range(NUMBER_OF_HOURS):
            data[i].append([])
            data[i][j].append(0)
            data[i][j].append(0)
    for k in range(NUMBER_OF_DAYS * NUMBER_OF_HOURS):
        line = input().strip().split()
        day = eval(line[0])
        hour = eval(line[1])
        temperature = eval(line[2])
        humidity = eval(line[3])
        data[day - 1][hour - 1][0] = temperature
        data[day - 1][hour - 1][1] = humidity
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_DAYS):
        dailyTemperatureTotal = 0
        dailyHumidityTotal = 0
        for j in range(NUMBER_OF_DAYS):
            dailyTemperatureTotal += data[i][j][0]
            dailyHumidityTotal += data[i][j][1]
        print("Day " + str(i) + "'s average temperature is" + str(dailyTemperatureTotal / NUMBER_OF_HOURS))
        print("Day " + str(i) + "'s average humidity is" + str(dailyHumidityTotal / NUMBER_OF_HOURS))

main()
```

Ok this stressing me out. I can't seem to get this code to run because of another error I am facing. What is this EOF while parsing. It seems to highlight the `day = eval (line[0])` for some reason and I have no clue why

Comment: It would help if you included some sample inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means `line[0]` consists of an incomplete Python statement. An empty string would do that, for example:

```
>>> eval('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

If your inputs consist of integers, use `int()` instead for clearer error messages, and check for empty lines.

There are better ways to build your data structure; a list comprehension for example:

```
totals = [[0, 0] for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_DAYS)]
```

This structure is enough to hold all the totals; there is no point in keeping per-hour values when you can just sum the whole thing per day instead.

I'd read from `stdin` instead of using `input()`, summing the temperature and humidity per day directly:

```
from itertools import islice
import sys

for line in islice(sys.stdin, NUMBER_OF_DAYS * NUMBER_OF_HOURS):
    day, hour, temperature, humidity = map(int, line.split())
    data[day - 1][0] += temperature
    data[day - 1][1] += humidity
```

and calculating the averages becomes:

```
for i, (temp, humidity) in enumerate(data):
    print("Day {}'s average temperature is {}".format(i,  temp / NUMBER_OF_HOURS))
    print("Day {}'s average humidity is {}".format(i,  humidity / NUMBER_OF_HOURS))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the problem lies in this section

```
for k in range(NUMBER_OF_DAYS * NUMBER_OF_HOURS):
        line = input().strip().split()
        day = eval(line[0])
```

I would assume you want a user each time to input a value and than process the input by eval?

I am not sure what eval is doing, but according to the error message the `line` variable is empty, or has `len(line) == 0: True` properties so that `line[0]` doesn't work.

If you use `input()` in python3, in contrast to python2's `input()`, it always reads the user input in as a `string`. So it is similar to python2's `raw_input()` function. Maybe your `eval()` function is missing the conversion from `str` to `int`? But again, I am not sure what `eval()` is doing.

Maybe just insert a

```
print("\n\nline: {}\n\n".format(line))
```

after

```
for k in range(NUMBER_OF_DAYS * NUMBER_OF_HOURS):
        line = input().strip().split()
```

and we will know more